# can LINQ being used with Sybase database?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Customer wants to move from SQL server to Sybase database. Don't know if LINQ can still be here? change is big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [article](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1056609) states that Sybase provide support for SQL Anywhere through the Entity Framework.